# Ordering by children (nested) elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `Category` model with parent and child categories (`acts_as_nested_set`). Every category has its `balance`, and I want to order parent categories by sum of their "family balance".

By "family balance" I mean this:

```
def children_categories(c)
  current_user.categories.where(parent_id: c.id)
end

def family_balance(c)
  c.balance + children_categories(c).sum(:balance)
end
```

I use these methods in helper to show it in views, but I don't know, how to use `family_balance` in `order` method in controller.

In fact I need something like this to be working:

```
@parent_categories = current_user.categories.where(parent_id: nil).order(family_balance: :asc)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `order` add an `ORDER BY` instruction to the SQL request. You can't use it because `family_balance` is not a column of the table. Instead use [`sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) to the collection returned by the relation:

```
current_user.categories.where(parent_id: nil).sort_by(&:family_balance)
```

Comment: Great. It works, but I had to create a new `family_balance` method in `Category` model.